# Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react from [this book](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/reactjs-example-building-modern-web-applications-react) but when I try to render this simple jason-based table data:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.6.2/remarkable.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>



    <script type="text/babel">





var App = React.createClass({    
render: function(){

var data = [
         { "when": "2 minutes ago", "who": "Jill Dupre",
        "description": "Created new account"
        },
        {
        "when": "1 hour ago",
        "who": "Lose White",
        "description": "Added fist chapter"
        },
        {
        "when": "2 hours ago",
        "who": "Jordan Whash",
        "description": "Created new account"
        }];

var headings = ['When', 'Who', 'Description']



var headings = this.props.headings.map(function(heading) {
return(<th>
{heading}
</th>);
});

var rows = this.props.data.map(function(change) {
return(<tr>
<td> {change.when} </td>
<td> {change.who} </td>
<td> {change.description} </td>
</tr>);
});
return(<table>
{headings}
{rows}
</table>);
}
});

ReactDOM.render(

  <App headings = {headings} data = {data} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Admitedly this because I don't know where exacltly should put the data but the book is vague about this. I tried putting the data elsewhere in the script but still got errors. So appreciate your help.

Comment: move `data` and `headings` outside of `App`, or instead of `this.props.data` and `this.props.headings` use `data` and `headings` local variable

Comment: oh yes, that worked. Thanks Alexander!

Answer (score 1):

**this.props** : your referring properties of  your class/component. In your example, the *data* and *headings* are declared within render function, which means they are normal var declarations. You cannot refer them using **this.props** instead just use *data* and *headings*.